# Multi SELECT query for multiple ids

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.3

I do a *SELECT* to decide if I send a notification to a user. (*10.3.23-MariaDB*)

First part checks if there are 0 unread notifications, if 0 no further *SELECT* is needed.

If not, I count how many notifications the user has since last equal notification (in this case there always one to count from) and check it against unread ones number *user_sess.unread_noti*

```
SELECT 'yes' AS do_insert 
  FROM 
     (SELECT unread_noti 
        FROM user_sess 
      WHERE user_id = 100)user_sess 
 WHERE user_sess.unread_noti = 0 
    OR (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM notification
            WHERE user_id=100 AND id > 400
       ) >= user_sess.unread_noti
```

Now I want to check multiple users for the same notification, and make it more efficient by doing the *SELECT* for multiple users at ones, for example something like this (INCORRECT example):

```
SELECT  user_sess.user_id
    FROM  user_sess
    LEFT JOIN  notification  ON user_sess.unread_noti > 0
      AND  notification.id > 400
      AND  notification.user_id=user_sess.user_id
    WHERE  user_sess.user_id IN (100,101)
      AND  ( user_sess.unread_noti = 0
              OR  COUNT(notification.id) >= user_sess.unread_noti
           )
```

The notification.id to count from, can be the same for multiple users because I *INSERT* them in bulk, so they will occupy the same "spot".

```
notification:
id        Primary   int(11) 
user_id   Index     int(11) 

user_sess:
user_id     Primary int(11)
unread_noti         tinyint(3)
```

Comment: Oh dear :-( Please stop, and see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try to do it in 2 `SELECTs`, regardless of the number of userids.

The one would get all the userids `WHERE unread_noti = 0`.

The other would get those that have `unread_noti != 0 AND ...`

I assume there is an issue that the table is being modified by other threads?  So, use a transaction:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ... WHERE unread_noti = 0          FOR UPDATE;
SELECT ... WHERE unread_noti != 0 AND ... FOR UPDATE;
...
INSERT ...
COMMIT;
```

Why?

- `OR` does not optimize well
- `FOR UPDATE` may solve any concurrency issues
- It is easier to think through each `SELECT` separately.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` and `having` as follows:

```
SELECT u.user_id, 'yes' AS do_insert 
  FROM user_sess u 
  LEFT JOIN notification N ON u.user_id = n.user_id AND n.id > 400
 Where u.user_id in (100, 101)
Group by u.user_id, u.unread_noti
Having max(u.unread_noti) = 0 OR count(N.USER_ID) > u.unread_noti
```